# import submodule then call function from script

Tags: python-3.x

I'm sure this has to be a duplicate, but I can't find the answer.

I have the following setup:

```
example
├── __init__.py
├── submod
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── subscript1.py
│   └── subscript2.py
└── toplevel.py
```

There is a function in `subscript1` that I want to call in `toplevel` when I run from the command line by:

```
python toplevel.py
```

I can do the following and it works:

```
from submod import subscript1
subscript1.my_func()
```

but what I want to do is:

```
import submod
submod.subscript1.my_func()
```

And this is giving an error of:

```
AttributeError: module 'submod' has no attribute 'subscript1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `submod\__init__.py` (which is now empty, I assume), add the following line:

```py
from . import subscript1
```

This makes the `subscript` module accessible directly in the `submod` module.

NB: The `__init__.py` in the root of your project is not necessary.